# Android Wear screen type detection - Round Or Square

Tags: android

Why on my wearable device does not recognize the shape of a square or round, The result is only square in my code? my wearable is moto 360.

the follow code is in onCreate():

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            String shapeDetect = "";
            View rect = findViewById(R.id.main_page_rect_layout);
            if (rect != null) {
                shapeDetect = ((TextView)rect.findViewById(R.id.rect_shape_detect)).getText().toString();
            }
            View round = findViewById(R.id.main_page_round_layout);
            if (round != null) {
                shapeDetect = ((TextView)round.findViewById(R.id.round_shape_detect)).getText().toString();
            }
            System.out.println("shape-->" + shapeDetect);
        }
    });
```

main_activity,xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/stub"
        app:rectLayout="@layout/main_page_rect_layout"
        app:roundLayout="@layout/main_page_round_layout"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

main_page_rect_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_page_rect_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rect_shape_detect"
        android:text="rect"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_page_round_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_page_round_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/round_shape_detect"
        android:text="round"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

anyway, the code print result is 'shape-->rect'

Answer (score 0):

Got it, because my application style isn't Theme.DeviceDefault